# Time conversion in swift in different format

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I want to convert the time string from 15:00:00 AM to 03:00 PM, this is what I am trying to achieve the results.

```
var str  = "15:00:00 AM"          //  "15:00:00 AM" 

let df = DateFormatter()
df.timeZone = TimeZone.current
df.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss a"    // "Jan 1, 2000, 12:00 AM"
let date = df.date(from: str)

let df1 = DateFormatter()
df1.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
str = df1.string(from: date!)   // "12:00 AM"
```

Not sure where I am missing tried different approaches but still I am not able to convert the times correctly.

PS: More of the answer, I am checking for the possibility of the conversion, as the time string I am getting is from server end and I can update them for correction.

Comment: How can be `15:00:00 AM` be `AM`???

Comment: Are you getting date in 24 hour format with `AM` & `PM`?

Comment: Just only "15:00:00".  Remove `AM` in "15:00:00 AM".

Comment: @NiravD  yes, this is what I am getting from server end, just wanted to be sure that it cannot be converted to the format I want.

Comment: @mangesh The date your are getting is not in correct formate, so you can make it correct by removing last AM or PM from your string.

Comment: Sure will do that, Thanks @NiravD

Comment: @mangesh If you still face issue update here will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Good Morning , please try this code

```
let now = NSDate()
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let result = df.string(from: now as Date)
```